# unable to locate package

Tags: 16.04, package-management, everpad

I am getting this error I need to install package `everpad`. Please help me to remove this error.

Possible(checked and failed) solution

1. I'd already ran `sudo apt-get update`.
2. In `software and update` I had selected `main server` option. Still I'm getting this error.

Comment: Then maybe the package is called something else. Can you find it in the software app (gnome-software) ?

Comment: no, its not there.

Comment: Okay, @AlexP has given the answer below.

Comment: You should try searching the package at https://packages.ubuntu.com.

Answer (score 1):

The development of Everpad appears to have been abandoned. There is no Everpad package for Ubuntu 15.10 or newer. Recommended alternatives include [NixNote](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nevernote/) (née NeverNote), or even moving to other note taking platforms, such as SimpleNote, which have better support for Linux.

My apologies for the misleading initial answer.

<strike>[How to install Everpad](https://github.com/nvbn/everpad/wiki/how-to-install):</strike>

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nvbn-rm/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install everpad
```

It appears that you need to add a PPA.

Comment: I have tried this. No success.

Comment: @DKP: What version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: 16.04 LTS, 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

There is no xenial repository for http://ppa.launchpad.net/nvbn-rm/ppa/ubuntu so there is no Everpad package for you to install. Simplenote is an alternative open source note-taking application. A 64-bit .deb installer of Simplenote 1.0.0 that works on Ubuntu 14.04 and later can be downloaded from [Simplenote's GitHub page](https://github.com/Automattic/simplenote-electron/releases/download/v1.0.0/simplenote-1.0.0.deb).

#### Features

- Sync – All your notes, to-dos and tags are kept in sync no matter the device you use to create or edit them.
- History – Slide back to view and restore previous versions of your note.
- Collaborate – Share your note with others and allow them to edit it.
- Publish – Make your note public with its own URL.
- Tag – Organize your notes effectively with tags.
- Pin – Pin notes right from the note list so they're easy to find.

Answer (score 0):

As @AlexP said -

> The development of Everpad appears to have been abandoned.

Though this doesn't answer your question but since you're looking for an `Evernote` client, [whatever](https://github.com/CellarD0-0r/whatever) an unofficial linux client for Evernote based on Electron. It works even on 17.04.